# how can we get the data list of dist using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to get the data from the below code:

```
data=[{'f': [{'@id': '6', '#text': 'Application Review'}, {'@id': '7', '#text': 'final demo'}, {'@id': '8', 'url': '', '#text': 'Sample Document.docx'}, {'@id': '3', '#text': '3'}], 'update_id': '1598972807556'}, {'f': [{'@id': '6', '#text': 'Track Record data'}, {'@id': '7', '#text': 'Track Record data'}, {'@id': '8', 'url': '', '#text': 'Testing Guidelines-QuickBase.docx'}, {'@id': '3', '#text': '1'}], 'update_id': '1597820400040'}]
```

i need the value or text
**output:**

```
 Application reveiw 
 final demo so on
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the  expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of looping through all the various dicts and lists:

```
>>> data=[{'f': [{'@id': '6', '#text': 'Application Review'}, {'@id': '7', '#text': 'final demo'}, {'@id': '8', 'url': '', '#text': 'Sample Document.docx'}, {'@id': '3', '#text': '3'}], 'update_id': '1598972807556'}, {'f': [{'@id': '6', '#text': 'Track Record data'}, {'@id': '7', '#text': 'Track Record data'}, {'@id': '8', 'url': '', '#text': 'Testing Guidelines-QuickBase.docx'}, {'@id': '3', '#text': '1'}], 'update_id': '1597820400040'}]
>>> print('\n'.join([e['#text'] for d in data for e in d['f']]))
Application Review
final demo
Sample Document.docx
3
Track Record data
Track Record data
Testing Guidelines-QuickBase.docx
1
```